# Google Analytics - one real time monitoring for more domains

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to set up google analytics for more domains with one real time monitoring.

I have one main domain and 100 subdomains.

```
Example:
main.com
sub1.main.com
sub2.main.com
sub3.main.com
...
```

I want to track visitors in one google account with one real time monitoring. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that by adding the same Google Analytics tracking code to multiple domains. The base domain from the Property/View settings are not relevant for data collection, so the same code will run on arbitrary domains.

(**edited**) Even less of a problem with subdomains. The default setting for the cookie domain is "auto", so the same cookie will be used for all subdomains. If you do not want this (e.g. if you want a user who switches between subdomains to be considered a new user) then you would need to set the cookie domain dynamically to the respective subdomain:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
  'cookieDomain': document.location.hostname
});
```

However by default the reports displays page paths, so you might not be able to tell from which domain a request originated; to do that you need to add a filter to your view that adds the hostname to the page path. An older but still working tutorial is e.g. [here](https://www.annielytics.com/blog/analytics/how-to-add-a-hostname-filter-in-ga/).

Naturally everything that shows up in real time monitoring will later become part of the permanent reports.

Comment: Since this about subdomains I have edited in a relevant paragraph. Normally subdomain tracking does not require any special configuration at all, and users to sub1.main.com appear as recurring user on sub2.main.com (because both set the cookie at main.com). But if you want the subdomains to be independent you might want to set the cookie domain in the tracking code.